# Crazy Number Base Converter Function

Tags: number-theory, functions

When I played with number base converter I found that, for example, if we convert 1234 in base 10 to base 2 number we get 10011010010 and we can write this is base 10 which will be new number. Morever, I found it can convert decimal number too.

I know that if we convert number in smaller base to larger base, sometime that number can't be written back in smaller base, for example, if we convert 1234 in base 10 to base 12 number we get 86A which we can't write this in base 10.

From all of these, I think we can write function f(a->b,x) while a is larger base, b is smaller base, x is in base 10 and number from this base 10. (a>b>=1 There is a base-1 numeral system too.)

f(10->2,1234)=10011010010

f(12->10,1234)=2056

f(10->9,0.1234)=0.10885573330667161547...

f(16->7,12.34)=21.13385214007782101167...

The function may be a little bit more complicated if a and b isn't 10. In fourth example, first, convert 12.34 base 10 to 16, we get C.570A3D70A3D70A3D70A4... . Second, convert C.570A3D70A3D70A3D70A4... base 16 to 7, we get 15.22442244224422442244... . Third, write 15.22442244224422442244... in base 16. Then, convert 15.22442244224422442244... base 16 to 10, we get 21.13385214007782101167... .

The question is "What is write function f(a->b,x) ?". I have no idea how write f(a->b,x) = (something in combination of +,-,*,/,^,sqrt,e,log,... or may have case that f = (something 1) if (condition 1) and (something 2) if (condition 2)).

If we can't write it, cound we find some property of this function for exmple d/dx of this function. How fast does it growth compare to x^2,e^x,log x,...?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much point in converting the number $x$, given in base $10$, to base $a$ and then base $b$. You will get the same result if you just directly convert to base $b$. As such, I will just describe the procedure for converting to base $b$. If you wish to first convert to base $a$, just use the same procedure as below after the first sentence for this base.

To convert to another base, I would first convert the $x$ expressed in base $10$ into the corresponding number, say $y$, using the sum of the powers of $10$ of its values. As for then converting to base $b$, do the following. First, have $r = \left\lfloor \log_b(y) \right\rfloor$. This gives the highest power you need to use. Next, let $y_{r+1} = y$. For each value of $z$ from $r$ to $0$, have $\frac{y_{z+1}}{b^z} = q_z + \frac{y_z}{b^z}$ where $0 \le q_z \le b - 1$ is a non-negative integer which is the coefficient of $b^z$, and $0 \le y_z \le b - 1$ is the remainder to use in the next iteration (if any).